# Having trouble finding a python package for genetic decision trees with custom loss functions

Tags: python, decision-tree, genetic-algorithm

Has anyone come across such a package? If not, are there any packages I could use to build it from?

Comment: Have you see this https://github.com/pysiakk/GeneticTree?

Comment: Yes but how do I make a custom loss function with that package?

Comment: In this case , you should implement your custom algorithm